# csv_import() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django

Hey I'm trying to upload a csv file using a DJANGO view but I'm getting this error
csv_import() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
my code is
view

```
def csv_import(request, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DataInput(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            success = True
            context = {"form": form, "success": success}
            return render_to_response("imported.html", context,
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = DataInput()
        context = {"form": form}
        return render_to_response("imported.html", context,
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

form

```
class DataInput(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()


def save(self):
    records = csv.reader(self.cleaned_data["file"])
    for line in records:
        parts = Part()
        parts.supplier_id = line[0]
        parts.name = line[1]
        parts.description = line[2]
        parts.save()
```

url

```
url(r'^imported',views.csv_import(),name="imported")
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: iv added the form and url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `views.csv_import` without `()` as the second parameter to `url`.

You don't want to call it right away but tell `url` which function to call when a matching request comes in.